# checking for inventory quantity in mini cart page Shopify

Tags: shopify

I am developing a shopify theme, i have created mini cart page as shown in this image, my website is: https://codeinspire-dev2.myshopify.com/cart
[image]

I am using vue.js for controling this mini cart page data, i have called

axios.get('/cart.js') for populating it with data, that call gives me cart object with all items on it, but there is no 
inventory_quantity property there. User can change quantity on mini cart page, but  i can't check if the product quantity on mini cart page gets bigger then it's inventory_quantity. How can i do that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options.

**Option 1**.
As cart JSON object doesn't provide information about variant inventory quantity available, you need to create such an object manually in the theme template. See the code below that will give you an idea how to get inventory quantity available for the items in your cart:

```
{%- assign cart_items_count = cart.items | size -%}
var cartItemMaxQuantities = {
  {%- for item in cart.items -%}
  "{{ item.id }}": {{- item.variant.inventory_quantity -}}
  {%- unless forloop.index == cart_items_count -%},{%- endunless -%}
  {%- endfor -%}
};
```

This will create a JSON object that you can use in your JS logic on adjusting cart items quantity. The object would look like that:

```
{
  variant_id_1: max_available_quantity,
  variant_id_2: max_available_quantity,
  ...,
  variant_id_x: max_available_quantity
}
```

If you need to get updated object on adding/removing cart items using AJAX -  create a new page template e.g. `page.max-qtys.liquid` to output this JSON object. Then on adding/removing items, you can get the updated object by requesting any page on your website and adding a `?view=max-qtys` query param e.g. `/pages/about?view=max-qtys`. Don't forget to add `{% layout none %}` at the beginning of the template file to prevent load your site layout file and just output the object JSON. Below is the code for the page template.

```
{%- layout none -%}
{%- assign cart_items_count = cart.items | size -%}
{
  {%- for item in cart.items -%}
  "{{ item.id }}": {{- item.variant.inventory_quantity -}}
  {%- unless forloop.index == cart_items_count -%},{%- endunless -%}
  {%- endfor -%}
}
```

**Option 2**
Use `/cart/add.json` on adding new items to the cart instead of `/cart.update.json` or `/cart/change.json`. Shopify will respond with 422 status code and won't allow you to add more items than available if you use `/cart/add.json` endpoint.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir.

Comment: Hi Vladimir i have made an object like you said but now i have another problem when cartItemMaxQuantities object is created after that if user changes your carts data saying removes items from it or adding new items, cartItemMaxQuantities  object is not updating, how can i update that object

Comment: Thank you for your response Vladimir i am trying to resolve this issue..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Within your slider-cart.liquid page:

```
<script data-cart-inventory type="application/json">
{
  "items": [
  {%- for item in cart.items -%}
    {
      "variant_id": {{ item.variant.id }},
      "product_id": {{ item.product.id }},
      "inventory": {{ item.variant.inventory_quantity }}
    }}{%- if forloop.last == false -%},{%- endif -%}
  {%- endfor -%}
  ]
}
</script>
```

Then, you can use `JSON.Parse()` in your slider cart JavaScript.